# html/php sql query where clause

Tags: php, html

This code works but the one belows shows an error

```
if(isset($_POST['month'])=='')
{
        $sql = ('SELECT 
        substring(pin,5,2) as District, 
        count(arpn) as RPU,
        sum(area) as AREA,
        sum(marketvalue) as MV,
        sum(assessedvalue) as AV
        FROM 2017_oct_land
        WHERE taxability= "T"
        group by District ASC');
        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'. $row['District'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="RPU">'. $row['RPU'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="AREA">'. $row['AREA'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="MV">'. $row['MV'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="AV">'. $row['AV'] . '</td>';
        }
include 'total.php';
}
```

**--with AND--** why do i get this **"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\reportview\pages\code2.php on line 20"** with this code?

```
if(isset($_POST['month'])!=NULL)
{

$kind = $_POST['kind'];

echo "MONTH : ".$kind."<br/>";
 $sql = ('SELECT 
        substring(pin,5,2) as District, 
        count(arpn) as RPU,
        sum(area) as AREA,
        sum(marketvalue) as MV,
        sum(assessedvalue) as AV
        FROM julcons
        WHERE taxability="T" and actualuse like "' . $kind .'"');

        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'. $row['District'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="RPU">'. $row['RPU'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="AREA">'. $row['AREA'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="MV">'. $row['MV'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="AV">'. $row['AV'] . '</td>';
        }
include 'total.php';
}
```

Comment: man this is so, wrong, use prepared statements.  give me a minute I'll fix you up...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ( untested ) but should be close

```
if(isset($_POST['kind']))  { 
   //why check month and then use kind? which is it..
  //isset returns boolean, not null, null works because it's false but it's not correct IMO

    $kind = $_POST['kind']; //what is this kind or month

    echo "MONTH : ".$kind."<br/>";
    $sql = 'SELECT 
        substring(pin,5,2) as District, 
        count(arpn) as RPU,
        sum(area) as AREA,
        sum(marketvalue) as MV,
        sum(assessedvalue) as AV
        FROM julcons
        WHERE taxability="T" and actualuse like :kind'; 

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([':kind' => $kind]);

        while( false !== ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'. $row['District'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="RPU">'. $row['RPU'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="AREA">'. $row['AREA'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="MV">'. $row['MV'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td class="AV">'. $row['AV'] . '</td>';
        }
include 'total.php';
}
```

Sorry, but you had some really big mistakes in your code.

Comment: Hello @artisticPhoenix! Thank you for the concern. I have two dropdown menus, named month and kind. where kind has values containing wildcards '%'. user must choose month and kind. and should be included in the query where clause "taxability='T' and month=$_post['month'] and actualuse=$_POST['kind']. thanks!

Comment: @scarredscarlet - well please take my advise on Prepared statements otherwise some Hacker will own your Database.